# spring boot oauth2 Can I get client info in the UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

```
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        return userMapper.findUserByUsername(username);
    }

    public void create(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userMapper.insert(user);
    }
}
```

I want to get the Client type When I loadUserInfo, I find in the SecurityContextHolder, But ,I still found the Client type, How can I write this code? 
Thanks for your review